# calling PLSQL procedure from Java

Tags: java, jdbc, plsql

Below is my Java program. I am calling a PLSQL procedure to update the Employee name. I turned off the commit in the PLSQL code so that I can do the commit and rollback from Java code. But even after I turned off the auto commit and doing explicit rollback, still the details are updated in the table.
How? I have no idea, please help.

Here's my Java code. In PLSQL, it just read the value and does an update statement . No commits.

```
public class TestCommit {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            conn = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:testuser/testpwd@//testdb:1521/testbx");
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            String sql = "{call testpkg.saveemployee(?,?)}";
            callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(sql);
            callableStatement.setString("name", "spider");
            callableStatement.setString("id", "A101");
            callableStatement.executeQuery();
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Close the statement
            callableStatement.close();
            // Close the connection
            conn.close();
        }
    }

}
```

edit: PLSQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE saveemployee(
       name IN employee.ename%TYPE,
       id IN employee.eid%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN

  UPDATE employee SET ename = name WHERE eid = id;

END;
```

Comment: Show us the stored procedure

Comment: Try adding this peace of code before your `getConnection` call (with proper try/catch block) `Class.forName('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver');`

Comment: Which version of JDBC driver are you using? Your code does look correct.

Comment: I added that line before connection, and it works. I removed it and still it works now. I assume the PLSQL body might have changed before I took the snapshot. I will confirm with the DB guys and update here to avoid ambiquity.

Comment: I voted for close, because as it stands this question will not help anybody who searches for problems with auto-commit or JDBC... I wanted to vote for deletion "wrong idea" but didn't find the option

Comment: I tried closing it by posting an answer, but I can mark it as answer only after 24 hours. I edited the title to avoid people searching for auto-commit or jdbc. Will edit the tags too. Sorry for that. I posted answer to avoid people from thinking some magic happened and it worked automatically. and may be the code and mistake might help someone, so don't want to delete it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I was calling a wrong procedure, there were two versions of the same procedure in two different packages,
one has the commit , the other one doesn't have the commit. I was calling the one that had the commit.
Now that the commit is removed from both procedures, my code seems to work now.

Comment: I need not provide an answer to this, but still I provided as an answer because if tomorrow someone has the same issue they can get to know how I overcame the above issue. And the reason Why I didn't delete the question is because the question as well as the comments are useful. Whoever down-voted this, please care to explain why so that I can improve if you differ with my thoughts.