# Commit/Autocommit or Rollback recommended after calling Stored Procedures

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, commit

It's not so usual to call stored procedures in Java so I fear the information online about the process is a bit limited. Usually I use `connection.setAutoCommit(false);` in the beginning and `connection.commit();` in the end with regular DB-Updates.

Before I wasn't using the `c.commit();` line and since this function is called via Ajax I saw in FireBug the Ajax-Request never finishes which made me add the `ps.setQueryTimeout(99);` line.

Right now my method for calling stored procedures looks like this:

```
private void callProcedure(int customer, int user, String stmt) {
        Connection c = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try {
            c = ConnectionTools.getConnection();
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
            //"EXEC CustomerUpdate ?, ?";
            ps = c.prepareStatement(stmt);
            ps.setEscapeProcessing(true);
            ps.setQueryTimeout(99);
            ps.setInt(1, customer);
            ps.setInt(2, user);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            c.commit();

        } catch (NamingException | SQLException ex) {

            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.rollback();
                } catch (SQLException ex1) {  
                    Logger.getLogger(CustomerProcedures.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
                }
            }
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerProcedures.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "SQL: {0}; {1}; {2}", new Object[]{stmt, customer, user});
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerProcedures.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } finally {
            ConnectionTools.disconnect(ps, c);
        }
    }
```

From the material related to my question there is one example for Oracle but rolling back, not committing: [calling PLSQL procedure from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892819/calling-plsql-procedure-from-java) - this example seems to be a good one since there was just a minor mistake not related to the issue itself. In my impression it seems fine to set a `conn.setAutoCommit(false);`.

In another example with only little attention nothing like that was used: [Java: Calling a stored procedure in an oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900708/java-calling-a-stored-procedure-in-an-oracle-database)

In other sources I there wasn't much to find either. Coderanch had a short discussion, but in my Stored Procedure is no commit (http://www.coderanch.com/t/621006/java/java/commit-written-procedures-called-Java)

In the official documentation there isn't much attention on the commit issue too: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html
They just recommend to use `prepareCall` instead of `prepareStatement` and `execute` instead of `executeUpdate`

```
cs = this.con.prepareCall("{call RAISE_PRICE(?,?,?)}");
cs.setString(1, coffeeNameArg);
cs.setFloat(2, maximumPercentageArg);
cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NUMERIC);
cs.setFloat(3, newPriceArg);

cs.execute();
```

There's just:

> Note: As with Statement objects, to call the stored procedure, you can
>   call execute, executeQuery, or executeUpdate depending on how many
>   ResultSet objects the procedure returns. However, if you are not sure
>   how many ResultSet objects the procedure returns, call execute.

But so far nothing to commit...

Comment: So where is the question here? Also, it looks like you are using Oracle but you tagged this with sql server. Personally I would leave the transactions to the database instead of trying to manage it in code. What happens if your code has a commit/rollback? Your code won't be able to roll it back or commit because it is already done.

Comment: I need to know if after a stored procedure it's recommended/necessary to commit. And no, I use the SQL Server, the posts were just about Oracle - but as it's JDBC the code is basically the same. Right now the procedure seems to block something in the database since the AJAX-request never finishes. (Executing the SP in the Management studio is much faster). Committing doesn't seem to be a problem, since autoCommit is turned off

Comment: It seems to me, that in all links they are using `prepareCall` instead on `prepareStatement` did you try that? I'd say, that in general you do not want to have `commit`s in a procedure, otherwise you cannot call several procedures in a transaction and rollback all calls if there is an error...

Comment: The default setting will autocommit any open transactions. If you are not using transactions in your procedures then there is no point in even worrying about it. This questions is really considered off topic here because it is largely opinion based. For instance, I completely do not agree with @Betlista. In my opinion everything around transactions belongs in the database. If you need to worry about multiple procedures then you should create a procedure with transactions that you can call. Keeping everything data related in the data layer.

Comment: @Betlista: It seems this Ajax-Waiting problem was of different origin. I recreated the procedure and now it's gone. Changing to `prepareCall` instead of `prepareStatement` and with/out commit there aren't much differences.

Comment: @SeanLange: So what would you recommend me to do? I'm not much a fan of the autocommit-setting since I had some issues where the statements were only partly called... That's what the rollback in the catch-block is for. In that particular case it's just one procedure - and after it's called the user can do what pleases him

Comment: What do you mean a statement is only partly called? That doesn't make much sense. As I said before, a procedure itself is not a transaction but it may or may not contain one. If you want to manage the transaction yourself that is fine but the autocommit setting is not really needed here. If you begin a transaction in your managed code it will NOT autocommit when you execute a procedure. The autocommit setting is how you want open transactions to behave when the connection is closed, not when a procedure is executed.

Comment: I just said once long time ago I had this issue - it's not topic related anyway... I just wanted to state why I prefer writing a `commit` in the end rather than autocommitting. In this case procedure contains some `INSERT`s and `DELETE`s.